# How to create different thread in CherryPy?

Tags: python, thread-safety, cherrypy, server

I am new to web development. Using cherrypy for the first time.

```
import cherrypy
import src.main

class Interface:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mypf = src.main.pf()

    commonhtmlString = """<form method="get" action="generate">
          <input type="text" value="" name="l" />
          <input type="text" value="" name="r" />
          <button type="submit">Give it now!</button>
          </form>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return Interface.commonhtmlString

    @cherrypy.expose
    def generate(self, l, r):
        self.mypf = src.main.pf()
        self.mypf.getLocalityInfo(l, r)
        return Interface.commonhtmlString + self.mypf.printC()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def explore(self, c):
        return Interface.commonhtmlString + self.mypf.printIC(c)

cherrypy.quickstart(Interface())
```

Above code works well. But when I open new browser or new tab and change parameter and generate new output ... it reflects across all open links and results in error.

Exm. suppose i enter l=x r=xx and result I get is xxx. Now if i open url in another tab and enter l=y r=yy and result I get is yyy. Now what happens is previous tab is not persisting to xxx hence if I click some links in xxx they either go to yyy equivalent links or results in error.

Can someone help in this matter ?
You can explain or give any external links or concepts. Ready to read up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what links you are referring to and what `pf` does. Most likely you don't realize that `Interface` instance is only created once, and it keeps the data between the requests (and you need to ensure thread safety for the global data). If it doesn't help, edit your question with a runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it's hard to see what you are doing with the submitted data. It seems that you are storing the submitted values in a variable/datastore on the server. There's only one copy of that variable, so users will overwrite each other's copy. You could consider either creating a small database and storing each user's input (if you have a way to distinguish the users). Or you can store the data in the users session, and reference it every time the page is viewed/refreshed.

http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html?highlight=session#module-cherrypy.lib.sessions